# Сохранение нескольких Object Controller'ов в Core Data

Tags: macos, objective-c, xcode, coredata

Здравствуйте! Во время экспериментирования с Core Data в приложении типа Document–Based столкнулся со следующей проблемой: имеются два Object Controller'а, но почему–то изменение данных одного из них влечёт за собой и изменение данных другого. При открытии сохранённого документа в местах, где должны быть данные разных объектов, отображаются данные только одного из них.

Слева рабочего окна предоставлено текстовое поле для ввода имени, ниже – текстовое поле для ввода числа. После нажатия кнопки, число передаётся в метку. Данными первого тесктового поля и метки руководит первый Object Controller, данные которого сохраняются.

Справа окна есть точно такие же элементы управления, за которые отвечает второй Object Controller.

Сохранив документ и открыв его снова, в обоих полях для ввода имени отображается одно и тоже имя и в обоих метках – одни и теже числа.

В чём проблема?

По скольку лучше 1 раз увидеть, чем 100 раз прочитать, то вот мой проект: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zyvpoj5uwj71okn/mDdV7xoVbk